# Angular Web Components - @Input not receiving the value

Tags: javascript, angular

I've got a problem where I've created a Angular Web Component (or Angular Web Element) and I'm trying to get a value passed into the component via a `@Input()`. This value is just not pulling through but I've made it all the same as any other `@Input()` in Angular. I'm very confused.

The code looks like this:

component.ts

```js
@Input() displayGroup: string;

ngOnInit() {
   console.log(this.displayGroup);
}
```

using element

```html
<my-custom-element displayGroup="test"></my-custom-element>
```

Why would the value from the Input? The value displayed in the console is:
`undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular Web Components work slightly differently from normal Angular components.

As you can see from Angular's official documentation [here](https://angular.io/guide/elements#mapping)

> The creation API parses the component looking for input properties,
>   and defines corresponding attributes for the custom element. It
>   transforms the property names to make them compatible with custom
>   elements, which do not recognize case distinctions. The resulting
>   attribute names use dash-separated lowercase. For example, for a
>   component with @Input('myInputProp') inputProp, the corresponding
>   custom element defines an attribute my-input-prop.

This means that in the HTML you need the following:

```html
<my-custom-element display-group="test"></my-custom-element>
```

Any `@Input()` variables that you declare, would need to be kebab-lower-case for the input where you will be using it